# Is there a way to remove the whitespace outside of a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, r-sf

I'm taking the code I use to create a static map to include on a shiny app. I have an issue though where the plot size is much larger than the actual plot, so the layout looks off. Is there any way to reduce this whitespace on the outside of the plot?

If possible I'd like the output to be only the plot itself.

[image: poorly drawn example of the whitespace I mean]

```
# reprex
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

lux <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra"))

p <- lux %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME_2), colour = "white", size = 0.2) +
  theme(legend.position = "None") +
# found online - removes the whitespace around the plot but not the external whitespace
  theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm")) 

p
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason your plot contains the whitespace is due to the constraints put on the coordinate system by `geom_sf()`.  The aspect ratio of your plot normally adjusts itself to fit the size of the window in a typical plot, but in the case of a shapefile (`sf`), the aspect ratio is determined by the particular [coordinate reference system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system), or CRS associated with that particular projection.  You've seen this before in maps, where there is a distortion in each of the maps that happens due to trying to project the surface of a globe onto a 2D flat plane.

So, `geom_sf()` results in a map with the proper aspect ratio.  If your view window or output image does not match that aspect ratio, then you will have whitespace at the sides or top to compensate.  The way to solve the problem, then, is to either change the aspect ratio of your plot (which will not look right and is not a good idea) or have your output image or window match the aspect ratio of your plot.

TL;DR - use `tmaptools::get_asp_ratio()` to grab the aspect ratio of your plot object, then save the plot image with that aspect ratio.

Now for some explanatory images and such that help illustrate why `geom_sf()` functions differently than `geom_polygon()`, and how you can fix the issue in a representative example.

#### Maps using `geom_polygon()`

Unless you fix the ratio of the plot area with `coord_fixed()`, `geom_polygon()` will always squish and stretch as the output aspect ratio changes.

```
library(ggplot2)

my_map <- map_data("usa")
p1 <-
  ggplot(my_map, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group=group), fill='white', color='black') +
  ggtitle('USA Using geom_polygon()')
```

Here's a square map:

```
ggsave('p1_square.png', plot=p1, width=5, height=5)
```

[image]

Here's a rectangle map:

```
ggsave('p1_rect.png', plot=p1, width=15, height=5)
```

[image]

### Maps using `geom_sf()`

In comparison, you can see the maps with `geom_sf()` always maintain their aspect ratio, regardless of the size of the output.

```
library(sf)

world1 <- sf::st_as_sf(map('usa', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
p2 <-
  ggplot() + geom_sf(data = world1, fill='white') + ggtitle('USA Using geom_sf()')
```

A square output:

```
ggsave('p2_square.png', plot=p2, width=5, height=5)
```

[image]

A rectangle output:

```
ggsave('p2_rect.png', plot=p2, width=15, height=5)
```

[image]

### How to Remove Whitespace?

So, now it should be obvious *why* you have whitespace... but *how do we remove it?*  Well, the answer is that you need to save your plot with the same aspect ratio given by the CRS used by your `sf` object.  What you need is a way of getting that information.  The function `st_crs()` in the `sf` package can get the name of the CRS used by your shapefile, but it doesn't outright give you the aspect ratio.  For that, you can use the `get_asp_ratio()` function from the `tmaptools` library, then use that to calculate your width/height.  It's important to note here that we need to use `get_asp_ratio()` on the **sf object** and **not on the plot object**.  In this case, that's `world1` and not `p2`.

```
plot_ratio <- get_asp_ratio(world1)
ggsave('p2_perfect.png', plot=p2, width = plot_ratio*5, height=5)
```

That gives us a plot output that perfectly matches the aspect ratio of your map:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the thorough explanation too